# SSRS report in CRM 'try again' issue

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an SSRS report with hyperlinks in.  When I add this report in to CRM it runs fine, and you are able to click on the hyperlinks.  What should happen is that it takes you to the related record.. however a CRM error box comes up with the options to 'try again' or cancel.  If you click 'try again', it works fine and takes you to the record.  I have declared the following expression in the placeholder properties;

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!MyEntityid.Value), Nothing, String.Format    (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}?ID={1}&amp;LogicalName={2}", Parameters!    CRM_URL.Value, Fields!MyEntityid.Value, "MyEntity"))
```

Does anyone know a reason for this bizarre behaviour?

Comment: Can you see any difference between URL that is generated in report, and the one where browser is redirected after you press "try again"?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL format should be similar to the link below:

http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B91330924-802A-4B0D-A900-34FD9D790829%7D

Also, verify the content of CRM_URL, this may contain the full reporting server path, not just http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com